# Sometimes Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, session, session-variables, codeigniter-3

After login after some random time when i refresh any page on website, sometimes it works perfectly, but sometimes it shows error like Trying to get propert on different lines of model and controller file.

For example, when i refresh the page error was shown in below function of model named user_model and controller named User.php:

User_model.php:

```
public function get_client_id($email)
    {   

        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get('crm_accounts');
        $result = $query->row();
        return $result->id; //line 135
    }
```

Users.php:

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$id = $this->user_model->get_client_id($email); //line 145
```

Setting the session value after login:

```
                $email = $this->input->post("email");
                $password = $this->input->post("pass");
                $result = $this->user_model->login($email, $password);
                if ($result == TRUE) 
                {
                $this->session->set_userdata('email',$email);
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',TRUE);

                    $data = $this->user_model->get_username($email);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('data', $data);
                    redirect('admin_view');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->load->view('all_field');
                }
```

code for deleting the session after logout:

```
    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $log = $this->session->userdata('email');
        if($logged_in || (!empty($log))) 
        {
            $array_item = array('email', 'logged_in');
            $this->session->unset_userdata($array_item);
            redirect('');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('error_page');
        }
```

Here, i got error on like 
**Tring to get property of non-object on line 135 of user_model.php and in backtrace it found error on Users.php on line 145**

I have noticed that when i get this type of error in model, i am getting data in that particular method using session variable $email in which the session data is stored. But i have put such condition in controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        if(!empty($_SESSION['email']))
        {
            $email = $_SESSION['email'];
            $data = $this->user_model->get_username($email);
            $this->session->set_userdata('data',$data);
            redirect('clientview');
            //echo "You are already logged in";             
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('signup');
        }
    }
```

So, if the value of session variable $email is not set than it should go on signup page.

So, i am not getting what is actually problem. Because sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes not. Once if i get such error, i have to clear my history and than i have to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

In `Codeigniter` you have a specific way to get form or set values in the session.

If you want to check if the session exist you need to do

```
$this->session->userdata('email');
```

Which will retrieve the stored value. 
And as you already do:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('email', $email);
```

To set a value in the session.

Additionally when the user is logging out yoi need to reset the stored value, ptherwise it will never be empty.

$this->session->set_userdata('email', '');

NOTE: What you are doing is of course not the best way to do such kind of stuff, as a login and logout system. I suppose you are just learning and you are doing this not for a production application.

If you do, please try to use `ionAuth` authentication library for `Codeigniter`, that you can find here:

http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/

And follow some tutorial about it:

http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/codeigniter-authentication

**Just keep in mind that user authentication is a serious security matter so be carefull.**

Comment: Thank you Franco. As you said i am learning. So, thank you for your instructions.

Comment: but i want to say that after logout i am clearing sessions by unset() method. but is there any connection between my problem with logout?

Comment: You need to follow the `Codeigniter` session rules. As I told you you have to reset the session $this->session->set_userdata('email', '" ");, and your problem is here: if(!empty($_SESSION['email'])).

Comment: Got it. Thank You Franco for your help.

Comment: Hey Franco, I have applied your suggestion to my code. but still sometimes i am getting the same "Tring to get the property of the non-object". I forgot to say that everytime when i got the error i am getting message like "Headers already sent."

Comment: Are you still using this: `$_SESSION['email']` some where in your code?

Comment: nope. I have replaced $_SESSION['email'] with $this->session->userdata('email');

Comment: As I sad it's important to set the session value before you are getting it. You have here just a few line of code and I can not follow you flow completely. If you want to use this approach, which I discourage, you need to set the session at the moment that the user post the login form.

Comment: I have just added the code for setting and deleting session after login and logout.

Comment: @DharaVihol please try to follow what I sad, don't do that in this way, it is a serious security matter. Follow a tutorial on how to do this in the right way, here is a easy one where you can really learn http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/